# A question about the relationship between forward price and Call

Tags: probability, stochastic-calculus, finance

Consider a call with values $C_t$, a forward contract contracted at time $t<T$, with time of delivery $T$, and with forward price $F_t$.

I am stuck on this proof :

$F_t = K + e^{r(T-t)}\times C_t$ , $\forall t < T, K\geq 0$

Some help would be appreciated

Comment: This can't be right since the Put-Call parity posits that: $(F_t-K)e^{-r(T-t)}=C_t-P_t$. In other words: where is the put?